# Rewrite URL: split path and add as a subdomain

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

What is the easiest way to proxy requests such as

```
https://example.com/path/path2/file.jpg
```

to

```
https://path2.different.com/file.jpg
```

?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a finite (and reasonable) number of subdomains, you can try with:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: path1
          uri: https://path1.different.com/
          predicates:
            - Path=/path/path1/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/path/path1(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
        - id: path2
          uri: https://path2.different.com/
          predicates:
            - Path=/path/path2/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/path/path2(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
```

If you really want a dynamic rule, this is not supported by the basic filters of Spring Cloud Gateway. Probably feasible with a custom filter.